# How to use nested grids in Bootstrap 4 with flexbox

Tags: flexbox, grid-layout, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 CSS with [flexbox](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/) and I'm having issues with nested grids. Nesting grids works as expected in Bootstrap 4 without flexbox, but when flexbox is used elements stack instead of arranging themselves horizontally. This code:

```
<main class="container-fluid">
    <form novalidate>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label>Single input</label>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">1</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="100%">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <fieldset class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Double Input 1</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="50%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Double Input 2</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="50%">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</main>
```

Creates [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA2jt.png).

**EDIT:**
Strangely enough, if I change the fieldsets in the second column to divs, the layout works as expected. I couldn't find any meaningful css differences between fieldsets and divs however, besides the calculated heights of the elements. What is it about fieldset that breaks the layout??

*Unfortunately I can't create a jsfiddle since the version of Bootstrap 4 css that is available via a cdn isn't flexbox enabled.*

Comment: Can you should your code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here's a codeply with Bootstrap 4 flexbox: http://codeply.com/go/vGxXpLucjT BS 4 is still in alpha so there are still many issues. Do you have to use fieldset?

Comment: Thanks for putting that together, @Skelly! I don't have to use fieldset, but it is both semantic and comes with a couple useful styles in bootstrap. I'd just love to know what the relevant difference is between fieldset and div/span/many others that causes it to place columns vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: Yeah, it is strange. I couldn't determine what there was about fieldset that was causing the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner next `.row` is in a `<fieldset>` tag.

In TWBS field sets have their margins set at 0, and *row* classes set left/right to -15px.  The combination you're using *breaks* the layout and the column thus wraps.

Try nesting in a seperate `.row` `<div>`, like this.

```
<!-- does not work -->
<fieldset class="form-group row">
  ...
</fieldset>


<!-- better solution -->
<div class="row">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    ..
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: In bootstrap 4, elements have a right/left margin of -0.9375rem. If you inspect the fieldset.row elements in the codeply, you'll notice that they do in fact have the correct negative margins, so I don't think this is reason.